# Picture that is visible to the left and the right side of the page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
Having two button that are visible, one to the left and the second one to the right, in the middle of the webpage.

Problem:
Do you know any jquery that can provide it?

Info:
*I'm using Bootstrap 2.
*This webpage (https://www.softwareag.com/corporate/rc/rc_perma.asp?id=tcm:16-123797) has the functionality that use "Contact us".

Comment: Why do you need jquery just use css or bootstrap col-x-6 to col-x-6

Comment: This is not a clear question, it is too vague. Please explain what you need more clearly, where on the page do you want the left button. If you provide a code sample it would also help.

Comment: it's simplae as abc is that your goal?

Comment: https://www.softwareag.com/corporate/rc/rc_perma.asp?id=tcm:16-123797

Comment: This website above has "Contact us" on the middle right of the webpage. I'm looking for this sourcecode.

Comment: I would advise that you simply make use of bootstrap as opposed to JQuery for this. Make use of the grid system.

`<div class="span11">...</div>`
`<div class="span1">your button thing</div>`

Use something like that. it's a lot easier. It doesn't answer the problem if you have to use JQuery so I'll just leave this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code for the example you've provided. Their *exact HTML* should give you what you want.

```
<a href="/corporate/contact_us/default.asp" title="Contact form intro" class="contact_fixed"><span>Contact Us</span></a>

a.contact_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 24%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 155px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  background: #80BD01 url('/images/b/contact_vertical.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

They're using an image to simulate the rotated text. There's a `span` inside with `display:none;`, presumably to help with screen-readers.

The main bit of the CSS you want is: `position:fixed; height:...; width:...; right:0; top:...;`.
http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/Ltzzawfj/